# javascript regex to disallow all special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, keycode

Here is a fiddle to start - http://jsfiddle.net/zuVpx/1/

**Javascript code:**

```
<script>
    function validate(e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
        var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
        key = String.fromCharCode(key);

        if(!regex.test(key)) {
            e.returnValue = false;
            if(e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="validate(event)" />
```

I want only characters and numbers. Keys like backspace, delete, capslock and arrowkeys etc should work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*old answer*, **update**] `KeyboardEvent.charCode` and `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` are deprecated. We should use [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).

```js
document.querySelector(`#validate`).onkeypress = e => /[a-z0-9]/i.test(e.key);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="validate">
```

Add an `id` to the input (e.g. 'validate') and use:

```
document.querySelector('#validate').onkeypress = validate;

function validate(e) {
        e = e || event;
        return /[a-z0-9]/i.test(
                   String.fromCharCode(e.charCode || e.keyCode)
               ) || !e.charCode && e.keyCode  < 48;
}
```

Comment: Really? It must be an old version of Mozilla then. Works in Firefox 19.0 here, even in IE8. Try using `document.getElementById('validate')` instead of `document.querySelector', or update your browser.

Comment: I have identified the problem. The problem is keyCode -> 35 to 40 are repeated for keys (home, end etc.) for eg # and 'end' are having code 35. Atleast here in my Mozilla 16 ;).

Comment: I see. The code is adjusted, now home/end, left/right, del/backspace also work in FF/Mozilla.

Comment: That's now working. Thank you very much for your continuous effort.

Comment: Hey! I was checking the above code in IE8. It doesn't work. It always return true. Can you please check?

Comment: I'm using IE10. Can't replicate that in IE8/standards mode, it works like expected. Check (especially) the *document mode* (should read: standards) - press F12, see top of the devtools window.

Comment: Tried a few things, but still not able to replicate, sorry. Will try later on other computers.

Comment: Problem detected. Best advise: leave IE8, it's a retarded browser. Anyway, the jsFiddle (@http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/fwcfq/) is IE8-proof now I think. Furthermore: beware of the previous version emulators in IE > 8, the don't seem to be accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`\\#{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/.test(your_variable)
```

It returns true if there is a match.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using an additional if clause? Something like...

```
key.charCodeAt(0) > 32
```

So...

```
function validate(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);

    if(!regex.test(key) && key.charCodeAt(0) > 32) {
        e.returnValue = false;
        if(e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the problem that for example the left arrow key produces the same `key` value as the `%` key, you could use

```
function validate(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var bad = /[^\sa-z\d]/i,
        key = String.fromCharCode( e.keyCode || e.which );   

    if ( e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0 && bad.test(key) ) {
        e.returnValue = false;
        if ( e.preventDefault ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    } 
 }
```

Any printable character should produce a non-zero `e.which` and `e.charCode` value.
See [JavaScript Madness: Keyboard Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuVpx/8/).

The above assumes spaces are valid - if not, just remove the `\s` from the negated character class.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for Me. Prevent Users from Entering Special Characters(Except Backspace etc)

```
PatternValidation(e){

    if(!e.key.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/))
       {
         e.preventDefault();
       }
},
```

This is triggered through binding html attribute with keydown event handler

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="PatternValidation($event)">
```